# How to deal with a Firebird table that's apparently both there and not there

Tags: sql, firebird

I've just had something very strange happen to me with a Firebird database.

I was trying to create a table, and the CREATE TABLE failed for some reason.  But now it's stuck in a very strange state:

If I try to `CREATE TABLE` again with the same table name, it gives an error: the table already exists.  But if I try to `DROP TABLE` that table, it gives an error: the table does not exist.  Trying to `SELECT * FROM` that table gives the "table does not exist" error, and the name does not show up in the metadata query:

```
SELECT RDB$RELATION_NAME
  FROM RDB$RELATIONS
 WHERE RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG=0
```

So for some reason, the table really seems to not be there, but I can't create it because something somewhere indicates that it does exist.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?  I've already tried closing all connections to that database, which has helped with inconsistency issues in the past, but this time it doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried manually sweeping the database? http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/gfix-housekeeping.html#d0e29976

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give details about what was the error when you tried to create the table, so I cannot comment it. But `RDB$RELATIONS` is not the only system table affected when you create a table. Maybe you are now in an inconsistent situation where some information about that table exists in some system tables and doesn't exists in others.

Another option is corrupted indexes in the system tables, so the record is not there but the index think it still exists.

Try to do a backup/restore and see if it helps. It it doesnt work, try to search for records related to that "non created" table in the other system tables (`RDB$RELATION_FIELDS`, etc) and if you find any, try to delete them.

As a last option, you may create a new clean database with correct metadata and pump your data to it using `IBDataPump`.

Comment: It's OK to add paragraph breaks so you're not posting a wall of text. Breaking it up into individual paragraphs makes it much easier to read - that's why they were invented in the first place. :-)

Comment: I think you are right; the most likely case is an invalid entry in the unique index on RDB$RELATIONS.RDB$RELATION_NAME

Answer (score 0):

I had a **very** similar problem, so I hope I might have an answer to yours. I also created a table "MyTable" and thought it was probably incompletely created.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable [...];
```

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

shows the table's name.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable;
```

results in:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42S02
Dynamic SQL Error
-SQL error code = -204
-Table unknown
-MYTABLE
-At line 1, column 15
```

Same problem with `DROP TABLE MyTable`.

I tried `gfix` to repair the "corrupt" database, to no avail.

I found my table name with `SELECT RDB$RELATION_NAME FROM RDB$RELATIONS;`, so I tried `DELETE FROM RDB$RELATIONS WHERE RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'MyTable';` which is not allowed, even to the user SYSDBA.

But there is one difference to your problem description:

```
SELECT RDB$RELATION_NAME
FROM RDB$RELATIONS
WHERE RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG=0
```

returned my table's name. That's why I'm not sure if I'm describing the same problem as your's.

#### My solution

It turned out I did just not rtfm and what it says about double quotes. The error message showing the table's name in upper case should already have given it away. I had to put the table's name in double quotes for the commands to work:

```
SHOW TABLE "MyTable";
SELECT * FROM "MyTable";
DROP TABLE "MyTable";
```